# Getting around scoping problems to effectively use chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope

Chrome's extension APIs make extensive use of callback functions and I frequently find that I come up against scoping issues as a result.

## Example

I am creating an options page and when I discovered `chrome.storage.sync.set/get` it seemed like the perfect solution.

In options.js:

```
var myOptions = {
    "option1": true,
    "option2": false,
    "option3": false
}

chrome.storage.sync.set(myOptions, function(){});
```

This works like a charm. So now in my content script I want to access and use these values:

```
// The documentation says you can pass null to retrieve all stored data
var myOptions = chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(){});

aFunctionThatNeedsToKnowTheseOptions(myOptions);
```

### Uh oh!

Unfortunately you can't do that. `chrome.storage.sync.get()` doesn't return anything. So instead I need to do this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(myOptions){

    var options = myOptions; // Hurray! I have my options

    /* Now all the logic for my function has to be put
       inside this callback. This function might need
       to call other functions outside of this scope.
       This is a mess.
    */
});
```

## The Question

How can I get my options out of `chrome.storage` and into the scope of all my other functions in my content script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not one of scope, but of timing.

```
var options; // everyone has access to options.

chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(myOptions){
    options = myOptions; // Hurray! I have my options
});

console.log(options);                               // No options yet
setTimeout(function(){console.log(options)}, 2000); // Options
```

I think the best way to deal with the pitfalls of asynchronous programming (specifically the nested callbacks you need to do) is the Promise pattern.

Here is a blog post to get you started with understanding Promises and how they help you structure your code better:

http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics

If you find it hard to understand from that particular post, google others until you find one that you do. Keep in mind that promises are not specific to JS, so you might find ideas and explanations for other languages that can help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables outside of the current scope.

```
var myOptions = {
    option1: true,
    option2: false,
    option3: false
};

function aFunctionThatNeedsToKnowTheseOptions () {

    console.log(myOptions);
}

chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (options) {

    myOptions = options;

    aFunctionThatNeedsToKnowTheseOptions();
});
```